# How can i dynamically change the size of an iframe when url changes

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

how to change size of iframe dynamically for iframe src. if src is http://-----.com/index , the iframe size height is 200 and width 400. if src changes http://-----.com/about , the frame size height 500 and width 700.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of this question is not clear! shame to see such on holds which only gives new users  cold feet to join and contribute Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an event handler for when the iframe loads. In this function, get the src of the iframe, and apply different styles based on it using a `switch` statement:

Start by giving your iframe an ID (if not done yet):

```
<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
```

And JS can listen to it:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').onload= function() {
  switch( this.src ){
     case 'http://example.com/index' : // Will fall through and execute same code as below
     case 'http://example.com/'      : this.style.width  = '400px';
                                       this.style.height = '200px';
                                       break; // Stop switch
     case 'http://example.com/about' : this.style.width  = '700px';
                                       this.style.height = '500px';
                                       break;
     default : /* Do something or not */
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't get inframe document height, so, you can't make it to change iframe height dynamically ...
All you can to is to add scroll bars.

Comment: I can see what @Anamika wants to do is changing the iFrame dimension and not its content (src) which is possible :)

Comment: And i can see Dynamically word.

Comment: which means instead of being static (always the same) it can be dynamic and change base on its src and different urls :)

Comment: Sigh ... You can't make switch onto every website in the web.

Comment: sure not, but who knows maybe what we try to do here is just for a couple of web pages created by the same person ;) . So it would be much more instructive to answer : "Yes you can, but don't  do it because such and such .... " still we don't know what is the use case but you certainly can change the iFrame size dynamically

Comment: In case question is wrong.